# Modify footer in Laravel markdown mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

Laravel 5.7. I have a markdown mail:

```
@component('mail::message')
Hello, this is an email
@endcomponent
```

When it is sent, a footer is added:

> © 2018 App Name. All rights reserved.

I want to edit this footer. I've published the vendor templates with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`. I've tried editing `vendor/mail/markdown/footer.blade.php` and `vendor/mail/markdown/message.blade.php`. But in both cases the original footer stays on the email. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you have to change both the markdown *and* the HTML files. In my case, I changed

`vendor/mail/markdown/message.blade.php`

and

`vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17970#issuecomment-281121329

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828322/laravel-5-4-wrongly-mix-html-components-in-markdown-mailable